# Taking JSON.stringify string output and copying into JSON.parse it Gives Unexpected token ' in JSON

Tags: javascript

I took and copied the string output from `console.log(JSON.stringify(employee);)` and pasted it into parse() but it fails:

```
//For the below I get Error: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
const person = JSON.parse("{'id':0,'firstName':'Andy','subordinates':[{'id':1,'firstName':'James','subordinates':[{'id':3,'firstName':'Aubrey','subordinates':null}]},{'id':2,'firstName':'Collin','subordinates':null}]}");
```

However this *does* work:

```
// prints out person as a JS object just fine
const rawData = JSON.stringify(employee);
const person = JSON.parse(rawData);
```

I'm a little confused as to why the first fails.

```
const employee = {
      id: 0,
      firstName: "Andy",
      subordinates: [
        {
          id: 1,
          firstName: "James",
          subordinates: [
            {
              id: 3,
              firstName: "Aubrey",
              subordinates: null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          firstName: "Collin",
          subordinates: null
        }
      ]
    };
```

[image]

Comment: JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes. It is probably your browser that shows it differently when using `console.log`.

Comment: "{'id':0,'firstName':'Andy','sub ... this can not be the output of JSON.stringify() , it is not a valid JSON.

Comment: *"I took and copied the string output from console.log(JSON.stringify(employee);) and pasted it into"* no you didn't.

Comment: I just tried to JSON.stringify() your object, and I got {"id":0,"firstName":"Andy","subordin....  so you are lying to us :P

Comment: I did the console.log of stringify in codepen.io

Comment: oh believe me I did copy it Kevin

Comment: oh I love the "this isn't about programming". Please

Comment: check out the picture I attached...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this :

```
const person = JSON.parse('{"id":0,"firstName":"Andy","subordinates":[{"id":1,"firstName":"James","subordinates":[{"id":3,"firstName":"Aubrey","subordinates":null}]},{"id":2,"firstName":"Collin","subordinates":null}]}');
```

or if you dont want to change json data , you can use that :

```
let json_data = "{'id':0,'firstName':'Andy','subordinates':[{'id':1,'firstName':'James','subordinates':[{'id':3,'firstName':'Aubrey','subordinates':null}]},{'id':2,'firstName':'Collin','subordinates':null}]}";

json_data = json_data.replace(/'/g, '"');

const person = JSON.parse(json_data);
```

hope this topic help you .

Comment: right I was just surprised that I could pass in the stringify value after I set it to a constant: `const rawData = JSON.stringify(employee);
const person = JSON.parse(rawData);`  but copying it in did not work. I don't want to replace stuff manually of couse, it was just something I tried